# How to put a php variable in the directory path in php

Tags: php

I have to go one folder back.

I have also tried using `.` but it is just going a directory back and cant find the exact path.

```
$target //is some php variable
$target_path = "../"+$target+"";
```

Comment: I think a basic php book wouldn't hurt

Comment: @Rizier123 i guess this post is just missing some source to get clear what the op wants :) Im programming php for years and also do js/jquery and and and... but sometimes I have mistakes like that because im looking to long at my source :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also go for:

```
$target      = "foldername";
$target_path = "../{$target}";
```

so there is no need for `+` (*whats actually javascript or php math*) or `.`

if you go that structure back  with `../` and want to select a folder or go into a other folder.

**You have to add a slash at the end like (*if target is a folder*)**

```
$target_path = "../{$target}/";
```

sample:

Your directorys

> folder1/folder2/index.php || your executing file
>
> folder1/subfolder/test.php || the folder where your target is

How to:

```
$target = "subfolder";
$target_path = "../{$target}/"; // goes from folder2 to folder1 and than into subfolder
```

Comment: still same problem if i echo $target_path it is outputting the correct path as ../xyz . but it is uploading my data in .. folder instead not in xyz which is required.

Comment: so you trying to upload a file ? if yes, please post your source too :)

Comment: adding a slash after "../{$target}/" did the work thanks for the edit

Comment: @AdityaGoel if it helped, may accept and vote up the answere :)

Comment: sure @Dwza if my reputation allows :p

Comment: they allow you to accapt at least :D

Answer (score 1):

Use dot`(.)` instead of `+`.

```
$target_path = "../".$target."";
                    ^       ^
```

Look at here for [***more***](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: it is not getting the right path it just goes a directory back

Comment: Since you added ../ at first. It goes one directory back.

Comment: but it is not going to the target as specified it just goes back . It is not able to find the target directory.

Comment: @Aditya Goel, you asked about how to go one folder back. it's not clear what do you ask now.

Comment: @Alex , go one folder back and then go to folder as specified by $target .

Answer (score 0):

a formel way of going one folder up in php is

```
$target_path = __DIR__ . '/../' . $target;
```

also don't use `+` use `.` to combine two strings.

**additional info**
if you want the code to be more portable, accross OS, use PATH_SEPARATOR like so:

```
$target_path = __DIR__ . PATH_SEPARATOR . '..' . PATH_SEPARATOR . $target;
```